# Search with %in% (set membership operator in R) broken on Stack Exchange?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, lucene

Can't search (on SO, with Lucene) for R language's %in% (set membership) operator, even with quotes.
(Note that Lucene's default behavior without quotes is even worse than returning no hits, it strips both '%'s and gives tons of irrelevant hits.)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328903/what-does-eg-do-in-r/1390408#1390408) is one such answer which cannot be found by searching for '%in%'
(It's in Jouni's answer, admittedly inside a `<code>` tag)

Note that I'm searching for %in% , not the %+% in the title of that question.

PS: as ever, I'm not expecting this ever to happen, just letting R users know:

**Bad clunky workaround:** search for **[R] "set membership" operator**

UPDATE: fixed end 2012

Comment: This is tangentially related to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100656) (Which by the way, doesn't show up if you search for 'lucene' instead of 'lucene.net')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:** As with the [question about searching for names.functions()](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100656), I believe this is a problem with Lucene.Net's parsing of code.  If, for example, you search [`"<code>%in%</code>"` +"numpy"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=56&tab=newest&q=%22%3Ccode%3E%25%2b%25%3C%2fcode%3E%22%20%2b%22numpy%22) it does show up in the results.  (I had to add 'numpy' so that it wouldn't return a hundred thousand results.)

Note that [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328903) with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328903/what-does-eg-do-in-r/1390408#1390408) actually has `<code>%in%</code>` not just %in% and perhaps it's Lucene's handling of the `<code>`.

Answer (score 3):

[You can now search for symbols](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange).  To do so, just wrap it in quotes for an exact match, like this: ["%in%"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%25in%25%22)

Comment: Awesome. (Make sure to remember the quotes, otherwise you will get no matches)