# Is Lucene.Net used directly or is it modified, much as PageDown is to WMD?

Tags: discussion, search-engine, lucene

Seeing questions come up like these:

- [Incorrect searching with %in%](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100831)
- [Poor code tokenizing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100656)

I'm wondering: Can I contribute a patch directly to Lucene.Net which would solve these issues?

Or is a modified version of Lucene.Net used much as [PageDown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown) is to [WMD](http://wmd-editor.com/)?

**Disclaimer:** I know nothing about this technology, but I'm willing to learn it in my free time as indexing / searching / classification / clustering is of academic interest to me.

Comment: Yep.  I got the link from [Jeff's blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/).  I think the trouble is that the original developer is now no longer responding to emails...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We pretty much use it "as is", meaning the core + contrib. We *did* investigate re-writing the IO layer (it is pluggable), but... that didn't end well.

Contributing a patch, of course, won't mean that we immediately *take* that update (although we're fairly <s>slapdash</s> *agile* about such things), and if/when we do that won't automatically mean that we forcibly re-index everything *immediately* (although we probably would).

Comment: Totally understand.  Just want to know how I can best be of help.