# Please consider making identifiers in code snippets searchable items

Tags: feature-request, search

I've been using the Search box much more frequently since Nick deployed his Lucene magic.  Beats the Google site: selector hassle and the results are generally good.  One thing it doesn't do however is consider words in the code snippets.  I do post a lot of code snippets and I'm having a tough time finding them back.  I'm concerned that if I can't find them back then neither can anybody else that uses the SO search box.

Sample query: [user:17034 filedrop](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A17034%20filedrop)

Does not find [this highly upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68598/how-do-i-drag-and-drop-files-into-a-c-application/89470#89470).  The user selector makes no difference btw, it puts a +15 answer on top.

Comment: See also [What about an upgrade to the word delimiter list for a more accurate search?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100656) (possible duplicate).

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is the choice of word separators. Google treats all punctuation as word separators with a few exceptions such as `c++`. Lucene on Stack Exchange is configured to treat `.` as a word component. A search for [user:17034 DataFormats.FileDrop](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A17034%20DataFormats.FileDrop) finds the answer you're after. I don't know if there's a way to configure the word separator that will satisfy everybody.

Comment: Well, sure.  The point I tried to make is that it is actually detectable that the common conventions no longer apply.  It is a code snippet.  Starkly obvious to human eyes, no doubt to a parser.