# Advanced search in code doesn't work?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please consider making identifiers in code snippets searchable items](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105766/please-consider-making-identifiers-in-code-snippets-searchable-items)

I put this query in the advanced search:

```
user:684229 addListener
```

Why doesn't it find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003063/get-bounds-of-a-google-map-v3-after-zoom-change/8239945#8239945)? It seems it doesn't search in the code. We may discuss if it's a feature or bug, but considering it a bug and fixing it would make the system much more intuitive and usable :-)

**EDIT:** That means maybe it needs some change because we are programmers and we do search for function/method names very often! Added a feature-request tag.

Comment: @Uphill if you close it these upvotes will come in vanish..

Comment: If you like it please upvote also the question linked by Uphill

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That post is found if I search for a little bit more of your code, so advanced search does work in code.

Search: [user:684229 "google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function ()"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:684229%20%22google.maps.event.addListener%28map,%20%27zoom_changed%27,%20function%20%28%29%22&submit=search)

As Arjan mentioned in the comments, it appears to not find `addListener` when you fully qualify the class name in your code.  Likely because search sees it as a substring of a longer word.

Comment: Also [user:684229 job](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A684229+job) and [user:684229 google.maps.event.addListener](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A684229+google.maps.event.addListener) do find that post. But indeed, it somehow does not find `addListener` when in the code itself it's used like `google.maps.event.addListener`.

Comment: thank you guys. That means maybe it needs some change because we are programmers and we do search for function/method names very often!!!