# Change state from discussion/support to bug/feature-request, or create new question?

Tags: discussion, meta

The usual case here on Meta is that I first ask, i.e. use tags [support](/questions/tagged/support) or [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), and then based on replies it sometimes induces a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Is it better to retag the existing question, or create a new one?
Retag has the advantage that question upvotes will not come in vain, creating a new question has the advantage of getting new attention and can be formulated differently. Maybe it depends on the situation?

Examples:

- from discussion to feature request: 
  [Advanced search in code doesn't work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114598/advanced-search-in-code-doesnt-work)
  (I already added the feature-request tag)
- from support to feature request: [Do shared link to ANSWERS also count for Announcer, Booster, Publicist badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114607/do-shared-link-to-answers-also-count-for-announcer-booster-publicist-badges)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323127/282094