# Is it okay to edit by-design bug reports into support questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, per-site-meta, bug-reports

Lately, I've been seeing a lot of bug reports on different meta sites that were by design. Some of them did get the [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) tag added to them. Many others got edited into [support](/questions/tagged/support) questions since they are not actually bugs, but I've always thought that was what [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) is for.

My question is, is it okay to edit [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) questions into [support](/questions/tagged/support) questions if they are by design, or should they have [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) added to them instead?

Comment: Considering that bydesign is a moderator only tag, you can't do that part anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see many new [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) reports here where the user clearly isn't familiar enough with how Stack Exchange works, and have no objection to retag them as [support](/questions/tagged/support). ([Very recent example.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/323122/revisions)) Technically, this conflicts with the author's intent, since a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

> Indicates a reproducible problem on the site that **you believe** is due to a mistake, malfunction, or programming error.

(emphasis mine). However, it's clear that they're actually support questions (at least most of them). Retagging them saves Stack Overflow employees some work; they tend to look at all questions tagged either [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

If a question already has a [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) tag, that means somebody already looked at it, so retagging them as [support](/questions/tagged/support) is kinda superfluous.